# Best way to extract out common implementation in all sub classes of a common abstract method

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class whose unfortunately I can't change the definition of, which basically provides an abstract method, somewhat like.

```
public abstract void do(Data someData, BaseInterface interface);
```

Now, every class is required to implement this abstract method, somewhat like.

```
public void do(Data someData, BaseInterface interface) {
    CastTheBaseInterface obj = (CastTheBaseInterface) interface;
    obj.exec(someData);
}
```

Now, I was okay with casting the interface but I have to extend this abstract class a lot of time and have to do the casting everytime whereas the casting will be done onto the same Implementation i.e CastTheBaseInterface. I was thinking of introducing another layer between my class and super abstract and solve the problem. But not able to think of the solution. My point is just that if I know beforehand in which implementation the interface is going to be cast to, why to do it again & again.

Comment: `do` and `interface` are keywords and can't be used as names

Comment: ***"vent"*** - I do not think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for a case when you have only one implementation to cast to:

```
public class YourNewAbstractClass extends LegacyAbstractClass {
    @Override
    public void do(Data someData, BaseInterface interface) {
        CastTheBaseInterface obj = (CastTheBaseInterface) interface;
        doCasted(someData, obj );
    }

    public abstract doCasted(Data someData, CastTheBaseInterface interface)
}
```

Then your child class would look like this:

```
public class ChildClass extends YourNewAbstractClass {
    @Override
    public void doCasted(Data someData, CastTheBaseInterface casted) {
        casted.exec(someData);
    }
}
```

In case you would have more implementations you could use dark magic that implies using generics combined with the dynamic casting:

```
public class YourNewAbstractClass<T extends BaseInterface> extends LegacyAbstractClass {
    @Override
    public void do(Data someData, BaseInterface interface) {
        // getting the generic parameter that you will define in a subclass
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                        .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        // dynamically casting your object to a generic type
        T casted = clazz.cast(something);
        doCasted(someData, casted);
    }

    public abstract doCasted(Data someData, T casted)
}
```

Then your child classes would look like this:

```
public class ChildClassOne extends YourNewAbstractClass<CastTheBaseInterface> {
    @Override
    public void doCasted(Data someData, CastTheBaseInterface casted) {
        casted.exec(someData);
    }
}

public class ChildClassTwo extends YourNewAbstractClass<AnotherCastTheBaseInterface> {
    @Override
    public void doCasted(Data someData, AnotherCastTheBaseInterfacecasted) {
        casted.doSomeOtherStuff(someData);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Should add that I didn't use any IDE, so it may not be working from the first attempt, but the idea should be pretty clear I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Java 8 or later, create another abstract class that derives the abstract class that you cannot modify and implement the method in this new abstract class.
Then make subclasses implement the new abstract class.

If you use Java 8 or later, create an interface where you declare a default method with the common processing. Then make your subclasses implement both this interface and the abstract class. You should so not need to implement it again in subclasses.

These solutions are not "beautiful" but you have legacy constraint so it should be acceptable.

Comment: Will this work if the method called on the casted object is different in every subclass, for eg, after casting, obj.exec , obj.exec1 and so on.